# Arduino and big servo

Tags: servo, home-automation

My dad told me, if i can mount some servo (to control 4 way ventil of heating) to his arduino-controlled home. But there is a problem... The servo does not have a normal 3 cables but 6 and I have no idea how to control. So i start some research about it and i found web site of manufacturer. There was also a Datasheet, but i dont understand it :D. So here is a link to the Manufacture´s web: http://www.mutmeccanica.com/prodottomutmeccanica.php?p=207
And link to datasheet: http://www.mutmeccanica.com/download_file.php?file=downloads/scheda_V70.pdf

And I have a question: Is any hope to connect this to arduino? Is there some shield for it?

Comment: I can see only 4 or 5 pin in that datasheet, not 6 pin.

Answer (score 1):

In the Arduino world, a [servo motor is a RC servo motor](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sweep). It runs at 5V or 6V and most of them can rotate 180°.

In an industrial environment or with the central heating in a house, the valves are often 24V AC. The most common voltages are 12V and 24V, and most of them with work with DC as well.
Sometimes the term "servo" is used for them, that is for example for a controller for valves with multiple positions.
To control them with an Arduino, the easiest way is with a number of relais.

Some intelligent valve controllers have an input signal. That is the one that you have.
The link to that datasheet is for a valve controller for 24V or 230V AC mains voltage. It has inputs to control it. Depending on the type, the input signal can be 0...5V, to 10V or to 20mA. Which one do you have ?

When that valve is in a central heating, it is possible to cause damage. First of all the central heating is tuned to the house. The valves work together with the pump, and not every system has a automatic overpressure-loop-valve.